# Recursively building a list of dataframes (in R) - is loop only option?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with n columns and I need to obtain combinations of its variables:

E.g.:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("a1","a2","a3","a4","a5","a6"),
                 B = c("a1","a1","a3","a3","a5","a5"),
                 C = c("a1","a1","a1","a3","a4","a4"),
                 D = c("a1","a1","a1","a3","a4","a5"))
```

I need to make a list that would have n-1 elements each including all the unique combinations of the dataframe variables. The first element includes unique values for each columns starting from the first and ending to the last. For each subsequent element I need to drop the first column of the previous appended dataframe. Like this:

```
myList <- list(unique(df[,1:ncol(df)), 
               unique(df[,2:ncol(df)),
               unique(df[,3:ncol(df)))
```

I managed to solve this with a for loop:

```
myList <- list()
for (i in 1:(ncol(df) - 1)){
    myList[[i]] <- unique(df[, i:ncol(df)])
}
```

but I was left wondering whether there was a faster and more elegant way to do this.

Comment: You can always hide it. :) `sapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), FUN = function(x, nc, df) df[, x:nc], nc = ncol(df), df = df)`

Comment: Thanks! It works. Small edit:  `sapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), FUN = function(x, nc, df) unique(df[, x:nc]), nc = ncol(df), df = df)`

Comment: Add this as an answer and accept it after grace period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sapply():

```
sapply(1:(ncol(df)-1), 
       FUN = function(x, nc, df) unique(df[, x:nc]), nc = ncol(df), df = df)
```

Answer (score 1):

An elegant solution would be a recursion:

```
func = function(df, n, lst)
{
    if(ncol(df)==n) return(lst)
    func(df, n+1, c(lst, list(unique(df[n:ncol(df)]))))
}

#> func(df,1, list())
#[[1]]
#   A  B  C  D
#1 a1 a1 a1 a1
#2 a2 a1 a1 a1
#3 a3 a3 a1 a1
#4 a4 a3 a3 a3
#5 a5 a5 a4 a4
#6 a6 a5 a4 a5

#[[2]]
#   B  C  D
#1 a1 a1 a1
#3 a3 a1 a1
#4 a3 a3 a3
#5 a5 a4 a4
#6 a5 a4 a5

#[[3]]
#   C  D
#1 a1 a1
#4 a3 a3
#5 a4 a4
#6 a4 a5
```